# Here document: no parameter expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any way to turn off parameter expansion in here document?

Shell command:

```
$ cat > analyze.sh <<EOF    
awk -F: '{print $NF}' asr.log | sort > tmp  
awk -F '(' '{print $NF}' asr.log | awk '{print $1}' |  sort > tmp2
EOF
```

I got this in analyze.sh:

```
awk -F: '{print }' asr.log | sort > tmp
awk -F '(' '{print }' asr.log | awk '{print }' |  sort > tmp2
```

Comment: Quoting or escaping the "limit string" at the head of a here document disables parameter substitution within its body. See: [**Heredocs**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the delimiter:

```
$ cat > analyze.sh <<"EOF"    
awk -F: '{print $NF}' asr.log | sort > tmp  
awk -F '(' '{print $NF}' asr.log | awk '{print $1}' |  sort > tmp2
EOF
```

This prevents the shell from expanding the here-document:

```
$ cat analyze.sh 
awk -F: '{print $NF}' asr.log | sort > tmp  
awk -F '(' '{print $NF}' asr.log | awk '{print $1}' |  sort > tmp2
```

#### Documentation

This is documented in `man bash`:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>           <<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  **If
>   any characters in word are quoted,
>          the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.**  If word is unquoted, all
>   lines of the here-document are
>          subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \ is ignored,
>   and \ must be  used  to  quote  the
>          characters \, $, and `.  [Emphasis added]

Answer (score 5):

You can quote the `EOF` to disable expansion:

```
cat > analyze.sh <<'EOF'
awk -F: '{print $NF}' asr.log | sort > tmp  
awk -F '(' '{print $NF}' asr.log | awk '{print $1}' |  sort > tmp2
EOF
```